# "Error in 1:ncol(data$x) : argument of length 0” when using pamr in R

Tags: r

I am working with a data by using pamr and tring to do a prediction analysis of microarrays. I tried an examples in this package and it worked well as follows.

```
*x <- matrix(rnorm(1000*20),ncol=20)

y <- sample(c(1:4),size=20,replace=TRUE)

mydata <- list(x=x,y=y)

mytrain <- pamr.train(mydata)

123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930

mycv <- pamr.cv(mytrain,mydata)

1234Fold 1 :123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930
Fold 2 :123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930
Fold 3 :123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930

pamr.predict(mytrain, mydata$x , threshold=1)

 [1] 1 3 1 2 1 3 2 2 4 3 2 1 4 2 3 1 2 1 2 4

Levels: 1 2 3 4*
```

However,when I run those codes to handle my data, I receive the following error:

```
"Error in 1:ncol(data$x) : argument of length 0"

*"z=read.table("shishi.txt",sep="\t",header=T)

mytrain <- pamr.train(Z)

Error in 1:ncol(data$x) : argument of length 0"*
```

My data was performed in the format of the example in the package as follows:

[image]

[image]

Did the error mean that there is no arguments in column? How to deal with the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From "pamr" manual:

> The input data. A list with components: x- an expression genes in the
>   rows, samples in the columns), and y- a vector of the class labels for
>   each sample. Optional components- genenames, a vector of gene names,
>   and geneid- a vector of gene identifiers.

In your example you've created a list with this characteristics in `mydata <- list(x=x,y=y)`, but not in your actual data use.

After reading the table into R, with `z=read.table("shishi.txt",sep="\t",header=T)`, you should create a list with `mydata <- list(x=z,y=samplegroups)`, where `samplegroups` is your sample group vector.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice. In my opinion, y is a vector of the class labels for each gene in my data. Is it right? If i have many genes and have to use the read.table function, what codes should i create. e <- read.table("**.txt",sep="\t",header = T), mydata <- list(x=z,y=e)? Is it right?

Comment: @carbo y is a vector of the class labels for each sample. I believe you have some technical and/or biological replicates for your microarray experiment, so you should define them here. For example, if your columns are, in order: Control - Control - Control - Control - Treatment - Treatment - Treatment - Treatment , you could add `y <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)`